# Tableau Live Connection Action Filters

Tags: tableau-api, action-filter

I have a dashboard that uses live data connection in order to extract the data, based on custom SQL with embedded parameters (The complete data is too heavy to extract).
This dashboard contains Action Filters.

When I load the dashboard, the data is being refreshed due to the live connection.
After this refresh, I want to interact with the action filters without triggering the live connection extract.
Although I choose "Pause Automatic Updates" the data source keeps being refreshed after every filter action.

Is there a way to stop those refreshes entirely while interacting with the action filters?

Comment: Choose the "Extract" Radio button at the top right of the workbook on your data source page.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'too heavy to extract?' will an incremental refresh alleviate some of the load on the extract?

In my experience, action filters work best with data extracted to Tableau Server.